# Insert one line into database where multiple rows are possible

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and have a table as follows:

Table name: `ip4_bank`

Field 1: `ip4_address`

Field 2: `nic_id`

By default this table will contain a list of IPv4 addresses with field 2 set to null.
What I want to do is run a query to assign a `nic_id` to the next available IP4 address.

The query I have so far is:

```
INSERT INTO ip4_bank (nic_id) VALUES ('1') WHERE nic_id = null
```

but this will fill up the table with `nic_id` of `'1'` where all were previously set to null.

Anyone have any ideas on how to just insert the `nic_id` value into just one row?

Comment: You need to define exactly what "the next available IP4 address" means.

Comment: When you say "next available", what criteria identifies this.  Or, is picking a random one (but only one) good enough.

Comment: I don't know about postgresql, but in some implementations you can specify `LIMIT` (or related) on `insert`/`update` commands...

Comment: Your schema doesn't include any indicator of what "next" means. How do you know that one row is more recent than another?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that 'next available' is the lowest IP, try this:

```
UPDATE ip4_bank SET nic_id = 1
WHERE nic_id is null
AND ip4_address = (SELECT MIN(ip4_address)
                   FROM ip4_bank
                   WHERE nic_id is null)
```

Comment: What does "minimum" mean in the context of an ip address? Certainly a lower first octet does not mean the address was issued first... unless you are talking about intranet addresses with policies that require this.

Comment: True, there's no way to tell the order in which the addresses were created (with the information we were given).  Barring an `issue_date` column or similar to use, this is likely to be the simplest and easiest way to perform the mapping (handily, the ip4_address should be unique, too...).

Comment: But if it's a string then this sorting method will be incorrect.

Comment: How so?  Unless there's some *required* order, we just need to update *one* record, and it doesn't really matter which one.

Comment: 110.0.0.1 will string-sort before 12.0.0.10. I agree with you that it will select *one* row based on some order... my point is just that the order here doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Matthew: actually min for an IP address is [perfectly valid](http://www.postgres.cz/index.php/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#Bigint_to_ip) for Postgres: `select '1.2.3.4'::inet < '1.2.3.5'::inet; -- true`. But no min, just limit 1, will be just as good.

Comment: @Denis, it still doesn't mean that one is "before" the other.

Comment: I agree, we could use a better definition of 'next available', but in the absence of any other requirement, the `MIN` (or similar) is likely our best bet.  Oh, @Denis - on DB2, attempting to replace the `MIN` with the equivalent of `LIMIT 1` performs *terribly*.